# Biquad bandpass filter IC?

Tags: filter, active-filter

Is there an IC that will enable us to have biquad filter given in this [PDF](http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/ptobin/3chapt07.pdf)?

Thanx..:)

Answer (score 3):

A biquad filter uses three op-amps like this: -

[image]

So get a quad op-amp like this: -

[image]

And wire it up.

Alternatively go to Maxim or Linear technology and get a highly integrated switched capacitor filter like this: -

[image]

Comment: Thanx....and design equation for the second circuit?

Comment: Read the data sheet and you'll see that switched cap filters like this are configurable and hence no simple answer to your request.

Comment: Datasheet talks about variable state bandpass filter not biquad filter

Comment: I was just using that particular switched-cap filter as an example of what can be found that is very integrated and high-order. Were you expecting some definitive list of devices that correspond to being a biquad filter?

Comment: But i am having a problem in the implementation of this circuit, because we have to make leaky integrator at once place but we cannot make a leaky integrator with this IC

Comment: Well, there's the quad op-amp package if you want to build a biquad but most people want a filter that does this or does that are are less tied to sustaining a certain topology than you appear to be so, why the insistance on biquad rather than defining what you want the filter to do? Maybe consider this page: http://www.filter-solutions.com/switched.html